# upgraded macbook pro 15" freezing and forces reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, graphics

Problem description:
Macbook pro 2011 15”, upgraded ram and ssd from owc. computer crashes, screen gets scrambled and only way to fix is it to restart. Sometimes it goes to black screen when restarting and hangs on it and the fan revs up to max speed.

EtreCheck version: 2.1.8 (121)
Report generated February 9, 2015 at 4:35:12 PM EST
Download EtreCheck from http://etresoft.com/etrecheck

Click the [Click for support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Click for details] links for more information about that line.

Hardware Information: ℹ️
    MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) (Technical Specifications)
    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro8,2
    1 2 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU: 4-core
    16 GB RAM Upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            8 GB DDR3 1333 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            8 GB DDR3 1333 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Old - Handoff/Airdrop2 not supported
    Wireless:  en1: 802.11 a/b/g/n
    Battery Health: Normal - Cycle count 1099

Video Information: ℹ️
    Intel HD Graphics 3000 - VRAM: 512 MB
        Color LCD 1440 x 900
    AMD Radeon HD 6490M - VRAM: 256 MB

System Software: ℹ️
    OS X 10.10.2 (14C109) - Time since boot: 0:5:25

Disk Information: ℹ️
    OWC Mercury EXTREME Pro 6G SSD disk0 : (240.06 GB)
        EFI (disk0s1)  : 210 MB 
        Recovery HD (disk0s3)   [Recovery]: 650 MB 
        Recording (disk0s4) /Volumes/Recording : 100.97 GB (100.76 GB free)
        Superdrive (disk1) / : 137.72 GB (37.83 GB free)
            Core Storage: disk0s2 138.09 GB Online

```
HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
```

USB Information: ℹ️
    Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) 
    Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
    Apple Inc. BRCM2070 Hub 
        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
    Logitech USB Receiver 
    Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver

Thunderbolt Information: ℹ️
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Gatekeeper: ℹ️
    Anywhere

Kernel Extensions: ℹ️
        /Applications/VMware Fusion.app
    [not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmci (90.6.3) [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmioplug.14.1.3 (14.1.3) [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmnet (0231.47.74) [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vmx86 (0231.47.74) [Click for support]
    [not loaded]    com.vmware.kext.vsockets (90.6.0) [Click for support]

Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [not loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusagent.plist [Click for support]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusnotifications.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]

Launch Daemons: ℹ️
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenusdaemon.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist [Click for support]

User Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.bittorrent.uTorrent.plist [Click for support]

User Login Items: ℹ️
    gfxCardStatus    Application  (/Applications/gfxCardStatus.app)
    iTunesHelper    Application  (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app)
    uTorrent    Application  (/Applications/uTorrent.app)
    VMware Fusion Start Menu    Application  (/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/VMware Fusion Start Menu.app)

Internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
    googletalkbrowserplugin: Version: 5.40.2.0 - SDK 10.8 [Click for support]
    QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
    o1dbrowserplugin: Version: 5.40.2.0 - SDK 10.8 [Click for support]
    AdobeAAMDetect: Version: AdobeAAMDetect 2.0.0.0 - SDK 10.7 [Click for support]
    Default Browser: Version: 600 - SDK 10.10

3rd Party Preference Panes: ℹ️
    None

Time Machine: ℹ️
    Time Machine not configured!

Top Processes by CPU: ℹ️
        10%    WindowServer
         3%    uTorrent
         2%    SystemUIServer
         1%    Google Chrome
         0%    fontd

Top Processes by Memory: ℹ️
    172 MB    Google Chrome
    103 MB    SystemUIServer
    103 MB    spindump
    86 MB    Google Chrome Helper
    86 MB    mds_stores

Virtual Memory Information: ℹ️
    12.77 GB    Free RAM
    2.04 GB    Active RAM
    830 MB    Inactive RAM
    1.53 GB    Wired RAM
    1.55 GB    Page-ins
    0 B    Page-outs

Diagnostics Information: ℹ️
    Feb 9, 2015, 04:29:24 PM    Self test - passed
    Feb 9, 2015, 02:14:50 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/installd_2015-02-09-141450_[redacted].cpu_resource.diag [Click for details]

Comment: 1st question, does it work in safe mode? 2nd question: you gave us lots of information but nothing from your console before the crash. 3d question, did you run apple hardware test?

Answer (score 2):

A  recommended debugging procedure would be:

Before proceeding disable (or uninstall 3d party stuff)

1. Start in Safe mode and check.
2. Reset your SMC since you changed the hardware and have fans running at full speed (sometimes).
3. Since you changed lots of hardware, run Apple Hardware test.
4. Reset your PRAM/NVRAM (EFI)
5. Clean your Disk from errors, and repair the permissions.